# Dummy variable depending on other element of same row in data frame in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame which is called 'total'.

I want to create an extra column with a dummy variable. This variable (let's call it dummy1) is 1 if the first column ('uid', a character variable) can be found in a vector 'vector1'

Hope you guys understand? Don't know why I'm having difficulties with this.

Thanks:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this, for example:

```
> df<-data.frame(uid=c("a","b","c"))
> vector1<-c("b","c","d")
> df$dummy1<-ifelse(df$uid %in% vector1,1,0)
> df
  uid dummy1
1   a      0
2   b      1
3   c      1
```